# Is it possible to pause Zombie Highway 2?

Tags: zombie-highway-2

Sometimes I get disturbed while playing Zombie Highway 2. I then want to pause the game, or see the objectives in detail (not just the upperleft abbreviated). Is this possible?

I know I can change my equipped weapon, but then I'll need to reload it (afaik). That has to chance to leave me vulnerable. I also haven't got the opportunity to view my objectives when I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated pause button, but tapping on your weapon while driving will stop the game. From there you can tap anywhere on the screen (except for buttons, unless you tap the weapon you were using) to resume the game without reloading or swapping weapons. Only tapping on the "R" from that menu will reload your weapon.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. So there's no way to see the objectives mid-run?

Comment: @Mathias711 You can only see them by tapping on your weapon while you drive, but as I said this doesn't harm you in any way, as the only way you can waste time reloading is if you tap on the "R" when you leave that menu.

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked that.